# Is the countable sum of a set of measurable functions also measurable?

Tags: measure-theory

It is rather straightforward to show that the sum of two measurable functions is also measurable. Therefore we can extend the logic to say that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n f_i$ is measurable providing $f_i$ is measurable. However can we take $n\rightarrow\infty$ and say that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty f_i$ is a measurable function?

Comment: Pointwise limits of measurable functions are measurable. Apply that to the partial sums.

Comment: Functions from where to where? And by sum of functions, do you mean like $(f+g)(x) = f(x) + g(x)$ or direct sum of functions on the direct sum of the domains?

Comment: I am not sure if your first sentence is so straight forward; I would prefer to have the math for this and know about what type of function etc. you are talking?

Comment: Functions from an arbitrary set to the extended real-domain and I mean $(f+g)(x)=f(x)+g(x)$.

Comment: You need some assumptions here, otherwise your infinite sum will not converge, think of $f_n(x)=1$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem for details.

Answer (score 11):

As Daniel pointed out, [the pointwise limit of measurable functions is measurable](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Pointwise_Limit_of_Measurable_Functions_is_Measurable).

If we define $g_n=\sum_{i=1}^n f_i$, then as long as $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} f_i = \lim_{n\to\infty}g_n$ converges, it defines a measurable function.

Comment: It should be fine for the partial sums to converge to a value in the extended reals i.e. $\infty$ or $-\infty$, is that right? In which case the pointwise limit is the constant function $x \mapsto \infty$.