# lebesgue measurability of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos nx}{n^2}$

Tags: lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Can u show that Lebesgue measurability of $$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos nx}{n^2}$$ and $$\int\limits_0^\pi f(x)\,dx=\text{?}$$

Comment: One must suspect that the reason for the down-votes and the vote to close is that this question is phrased a bit too much in the style suitable for assigning homework.

Comment: For the first part of the question see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/457342/is-the-countable-sum-of-a-set-of-measurable-functions-also-measurable).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The series converges to the pointwise limit of a sequence of continuous functions, so is measurable. The function $f$ is bounded by $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}6$, so the dominated convergence theorem implies you can swap the sum and integral:
$$\int_0^\pi f(x)\ \mathrm{d}x=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_0^\pi\frac{\cos nx}{n^2}\ \mathrm{d}x=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1n\sin nx\bigg|_{x=0}^\pi=0.$$